# How do I use NSURL fileURLWithPath with a fragment?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, nsurl

I have an IOS project with html file resources shown in a webview. These html files have different sections which correspond to fragments (eg, index.html#section1, index.html#section2), which I would like to load in the webview. Unfortunately using `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]` does not work with fragments. The `#` is converted to `%23` in the url, and the file is not found. If I use the `[NSURL URLWithString:url]` method, it works, but this method cannot load local resources.

Is there a way to have the webview load the local resource url with the fragment?

Comment: http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/data-management/how-to-read-a-file-from-your-application-bundle

Comment: nope, this wasn't much help. It seems to be impossible...

Answer (score 3):

As you have noticed, this seems to be impossible for file URLs, but you could use a workaround if you don't mind:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location.hash = '#section2';"];
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not obvious how Apple intended this sort of navigation to be triggered. There might be several ways to do it, but this one does the trick for me:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/full/path/to/index.html"];
NSString *fragment = @"#section1";
url = [NSURL URLWithString:fragment relativeToURL:url];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```